# How to add and remove background color of multiple boxes on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

When I am clicking a box, background of page should change to the color of box (that is happening), but what I want is whichever box I clicked last , that box color should also change.
I am also achieving to add color to box that I clicked but when I clicked the next box the color on previous box is not removing. I want only one box(last clicked) to have color.

```js
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let body = document.body;

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let bgColor = e.target.id;
    body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

    if (e.target.id === "white" || e.target.id === "yellow") {
      h2.style.color = "black";
      p.style.color = "black";
    } else {
      h2.style.color = "white";
      p.style.color = "white";
    }

    // if(e.currentTarget.id === bgColor){
    //   box.style.backgroundColor = "#343434";
    // }else {
    //   box.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    // }
  }, false)
})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-block: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#boxes #grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Color Switcher</h2>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="box" id="grey"></div>
    <div class="box" id="white"></div>
    <div class="box" id="blue"></div>
    <div class="box" id="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Click the boxes to change the background color of the page as box color</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by iterating over the rest of the boxes each time the active box changes, and adjusting their background colors accordingly.

This example sets the active box to gray and the rest of the boxes to match the background

```js
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let body = document.body;

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let bgColor = e.target.id;
    body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

    if (e.target.id === "white" || e.target.id === "yellow") {
      h2.style.color = "black";
      p.style.color = "black";
    } else {
      h2.style.color = "white";
      p.style.color = "white";
    }

    boxes.forEach((box2) => {
      if (e.currentTarget.id == box2.id) {
        box2.style.backgroundColor = "#343434";
      } else {
        box2.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
      }
    })
  }, false)
})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-block: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#boxes #grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Color Switcher</h2>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="box" id="grey"></div>
    <div class="box" id="white"></div>
    <div class="box" id="blue"></div>
    <div class="box" id="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Click the boxes to change the background color of the page as box color</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But what I wanted was other boxes to have color of their id not transparent. So set box2.id as color.

Answer (score 0):

```
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let body = document.body;
let lastClickedBox = null;

boxes.forEach((box) => {
box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // Remove color from the last clicked box
if (lastClickedBox) {
  lastClickedBox.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

let bgColor = e.target.id;
body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

// Set the color for h2 and p based on the clicked box color
if (bgColor === "white" || bgColor === "yellow") {
  h2.style.color = "black";
  p.style.color = "black";
} else {
  h2.style.color = "white";
  p.style.color = "white";
}

// Set background color for the clicked box
e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#343434";

// Update the last clicked box
lastClickedBox = e.target;
}, false);
});
```

Now check if this works

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: It seems we have to iterate boxes to get result. Below is the answer by @smallpepperz you can read .

Comment: ok great if it works.. i think i didnt understood the problem correctly... 